# File download URLs sharing webapp that checks for duplicates

Tags: file-management, web-services, archiving, multi-user, duplicate-files

I'm looking for a web-based system that supports the following workflow:

1. User enters a URL of a file and some metadata
2. The software downloads the file (via http, ftp, torrent?) and calculates one or more hashes (MD5, SHA, etc.)
3. If it's a duplicate, the software adds the URL to the file's list of mirrors

It needs user management and maybe moderation like a wiki or web forum.

I thought of using a wiki but I think it would be too cumbersome. Maybe a document management system?

Musicbrainz is similar to what I am looking for, but for files and URLs.

Comment: Should the software also show a list of the links? Does this list also require login, or is it publicly viewable?

Comment: Should the software discard the files after calculating their checksum? Or store them software? Or even make them available for download?

Comment: @Nicolas The software needs to show the list of mirrors for each file, and it should be publicly viewable. Whether it stores or discards the file after calculating the checksum doesn't matter to me, I would just like to see what kind of software is out there now.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information, thanks! :-)

Comment: Do you want to host it yourself on your server, or is an existing service OK? Should it be free? If not what is your budget?